# PKG slows down on FreeBSD installed on VirtualBox

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, vmware

Why `pkg install` is so slow that downloading and installing even nano takes about 2 min.? Every other commands works normal like on physical machine but `pkg` slows down too much that sometimes it's better to install from `ports`. Downloading speed is normal but time between next operation takes too much time.

I've tried install it on VMware, installing other versions of FreeBSD etc., with the same results. How to fix it?

Comment: Are there similar slowdowns with other applications using networking? IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

Often delays are caused by some problems with the host name resolution. Even sometimes the host's own host name.

Make sure that you have an entry for your host name in your `/etc/hosts`.

It should look like:

```
v.w.x.y        myhost.example.org
```

where `v.w.x.y` is your IP and `myhost.example.org` is the output of `hostname -f`.

Furthermore, check if the file `/etc/resolv.conf` exists and contains valid `nameserver` entries. It is possible that there is a dead nameserver for some reason.

Be aware that `/etc/resolv.conf` is in some cases generated automatically. You should still check, if it was generated correctly.

A simple valid configuration looks like this:

```
domain example.org
nameserver p.q.r.s
```

The first line is optional and is a hint for the resolver what is the network domain your computer uses for non-FQDNs (it will be appended automatically). The `nameserver` line is important and needs to have the IP for your DNS server (here: `p.q.r.s`). The DNS server must be reachable. Check this with: `host google.com p.q.r.s` for example. It should respond without a large delay.